# Navbar item moves down when resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first responsive website. I have a navbar inside a container that is centered horizontally.
Everything has a size with a percentage (is there a term for this?). The navbar scales down when I resize the window correctly. But my last list item (navbar item) will move down.

I have tried a lot with the min-width stuff, and I know it has something to do with this. But all solutions on the internet say I should give the navbar (or the ul?) a fixed width (xxxx px). This I don't want because I want it to fully scale.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="navbaritem">Test1</span></li>
        <li><span class="navbaritem">Test2</span></li>
        <li><span class="navbaritem">Test3</span></li>
        <li><span class="navbaritem">Test4</span></li>
        <li><span class="navbaritem">Test5</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html
{
        width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    background-image:url(images/background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container
{
    height:100%;
    width:73.20%;
    background-color:#00CC00;
    margin: auto;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
#navbar
{
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:13.28125%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
nav {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:13.28125%;
}
nav ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav li
{
    display: table;
    float:left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:#333;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.navbaritem
{
    font-family: Cambria;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    font-size:36px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine... http://jsfiddle.net/rx8bt8wq/ - by the way, you're defining `#navbar` in your CSS but I don't see any HTML element with that id.

Comment: That's correct, that #navbar was a test. I forgot to leave that out! As you can see in the fiddle the 5th test li item is not shown. Its probably moved down. Just like it does when resizing the original website.

Comment: If you change `nav li` width to `width:15%;` you can see test5 so that means you have calculated the percentages wrong I guess. I'd recommend following @Billy's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the width of the menu item to 20% and apply `box-sizing:border-box`. Your problem was due to insufficient width at smaller screen sizes when you are mixing border size in `px` and width in `%`.

[See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1yr3yj8/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your fiddle it works great! But when I resize my screen it the last item still falls down. Also, if I just remove the border it stills does the falling down thingie.

Comment: Do you have the full code or share the link to your website? That means there's probably something else affecting it.

Comment: I've edited the main post with the full code. I've added a navbaritem just for the text. Before and after this implementation the last item still goes down.

Comment: @user2014780 : When you applied `display:table` and `display:table-cell` for the menu and menu items, they would break into a new row if the content exceeds the width. Removing those will allow them to fit in a row regardless of the width of its content. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vurx0t48/)